# Android ZBar scanner library weird behaviour

Tags: android, zbar

I'm trying to implement in Android Studio an app which uses Zbar scanner library (https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner).
I've imported it into my IDE and after a long series of bleeding attempts to reorganize the compatibility of the various versions of the libraries, I've chosen to modify the existing example which uses the Zbar library.

Here comes the strange behaviour: When it comes to get to a new Activity (not one already existing in the original example), the app crashes with no errors or exceptions.

I sat "No filters" for the logs of my IDE, and the logs that I can see when this app crashes are:

```
04-03 16:22:42.381 2513-2513/? E/Thermal-daemon: [ap] temp_new :33  temp_old :34
04-03 16:22:42.382 2513-2513/? E/Thermal-daemon: Report temperature: [ap] temp :33  report_threshold:1
04-03 16:22:43.644 3085-3520/? E/InputReader: QEEXO fs_classify_touch NULL, not calling FingerSense
04-03 16:22:43.702 3085-3520/? E/InputReader: QEEXO fs_touch_up NULL, not calling FingerSense
04-03 16:22:43.728 3085-3520/? E/InputReader: QEEXO fs_classify_touch NULL, not calling FingerSense
04-03 16:22:43.730 3085-3085/? E/QosMonitor: query:IPQos is not initial!!
04-03 16:22:43.757 3085-3103/? E/ReportTools: This is not beta user build
04-03 16:22:43.790 2484-2484/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/1360/oom_score_adj; errno=22
04-03 16:22:43.820 3085-3520/? E/InputReader: QEEXO fs_touch_up NULL, not calling FingerSense
04-03 16:22:43.828 3713-4443/? E/HwSystemManager: LeisureTrafficSetting:result is empty
04-03 16:22:43.865 3085-3519/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '8304ce5 me.dm7.barcodescanner.zbar.sample/me.dm7.barcodescanner.zbar.sample.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-03 16:22:43.867 3085-3095/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102
04-03 16:22:43.896 583-595/? E/TotemWeather: WidgetUtils getWidgetShowCityInfo return myLocation
04-03 16:22:43.899 4135-4207/? E/HwLauncher: SettingsEx , no such field.
04-03 16:22:43.963 2486-2486/? E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
04-03 16:22:44.012 2486-2486/? E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
04-03 16:22:44.146 2486-2486/? E/hwcomposer: setGpuBoost:228: Can't open /sys/class/devfreq/gpufreq/max_freq: Permission denied
04-03 16:22:44.494 2486-2486/? E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: here is my code: https://github.com/alessandroargentieri/ZbarExample comparing to the original one, I want the app to be launched from SplashActivity.class which is a new activity I created.

Answer (score 2):

You have to go in `AndroidManifest.xml` and set your `SplashActivity.class` as the launching activity like this:

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
          android:theme="@style/FullScreenTheme"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: thank you but there is already the intent filter sat, as you can see in github code